# Excel - Keep calculation results as new rows on a separate sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have quite a complicated workbook with not so straight forward calculations using distribution averages. At the end of the workbook is a resultant value in a particular cell. Every time the work book re-calculates that value changes slightly. Is there a way I can save all these values every time I re-calculate to a new cell? Ideally I would like to do this 100+ times to be able to plot a graph against the possible values and get an average.

Would a Macro be able to do this job? If so... where do I start?

Thanks!

Comment: VBA would be the ideal way to do it.  Set your worksheet to manually recalculate.  Tie your macro to a button.  The macro would would cause the workbook to calculate once and place your single value in the next blank cell in a given range.That range could be preconfigured to be part of the data series for the graph, or you could put that next value into the data series bie the VBA script as well.  Just one potential approach.  What is causing the recalculation?  I am just wondering if it is one of the RND functions that generates a new number on every sheet recalc.  if so that could be moved.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to subscribe to the `Workbook` `Calculate` event. In order to do so, open the VBE by pressing `ALT + F11`. On the left side, you should see the `Project Explorer` tree view (if not, press `CTRL + R`). Right click on `ThisWorkbook`, then select `View Code`. This opens up a text editor window. At the top of this window, there are two dropdown boxes. In the left dropdown, select `Workbook`. In the right dropdown, select `SheetCalculate`.

Now, the workbook will perform an action at each calculation. Below, I have a sample script. There is a formula in `Sheet2`, cell `A1` for which we want the history. See if you can adapt the code to your needs, or reach out with more information if your need it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim sData As Worksheet
    Dim nNewRow As Long

    Set sData = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    nNewRow = sData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    sData.Cells(nNewRow, 1).Value = sData.Range("A1").Value

End Sub
```